# tr command has no effect when used in $() and saved in a variable

Tags: shell, tr

If I run in the CLI:

```
curl time.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' | tr " " "\n"
```

then, as expected, I get a list of sanitized links from the page to `STDOUT`, each on new line.

However, when I save that to a variable and try to `echo` that from a `script.sh`:

```
PAGE_LINKS=$(curl time.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' | tr " " "\n")
echo $PAGE_LINKS
```

I get all links on one line, space separated. So as if the `tr` was ignored.

I tried multiple things including something like

```
HREFS=$(tr " " "\n" < "{PAGE_LINKS}")
echo $HREFS
```

But then I get `file too long` error. Any suggestions?

Comment: see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: And [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not `tr`, the problem resides in how you are output-ing the variable expansion:

```
echo $PAGE_LINKS
```

Quote the variable expansion:

```
echo "$PAGE_LINKS"
```

otherwise the expansion will go through word splitting according to the value of `IFS` (space, tab, newline by default), and pathname expansion (`*`, `?`, `[]`).

In your case, the word splitting is happening, and each newline separated element is being taken individually, and being shown as space separated entities finally. Using quotes will prevent word splitting (and pathname expansion), so the whole expansion will be taken as a single entity.

Comment: Yep, that fixed the problem. Thanks a lot. Will accept when possible.

Answer (score 5):

According to the `bash` man page for the `$(command)` construct:

> Bash  performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any
>   trailing newlines  deleted.   Embedded  newlines are  not  deleted, 
>   but  they may be removed during word splitting.

So `tr` is not the problem, but rather `bash` either deletes the newlines if they are trailing, and removes any other newlines during word splitting. This is behavior as documented.

I believe you want this behavior in most places. If you have a file with a list of file names in it, then:

```
for FILENAME in $(cat somefile)
do
     ...
done
```

Iterates over the list of file names. You wouldn't want the newlines in `somefile` to mess up your list of words to use as filenames, and maybe even mess up your for-do-done loop.